# (if any) meaning in legal context

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

What does 'if any' mean in the legal context below?

When the Registrar receives under subsection 33(1), 34(1) or 35(1)
or (2) an application or notice (as the case may be) from the payee
or payer of a registrable maintenance liability, the Registrar must,
make such variations **(if any)** to the particulars entered in the Child Support
Register in relation to the liability...

My interpretation would be that 'if any' means that there may be a possibility that the Registrar could decide not to make variations to the Child Support Register.  Am I correct?
Thank you.  Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: can you provide the whole paragraph?

Comment: Hi, Alan, it's from Child Support (Registration and Collection) Act 1988 (Australia). 
36 Registrar to vary Child Support Register on receipt of
notification or application
(1) When the Registrar receives under subsection 33(1), 34(1) or 35(1)
or (2) an application or notice (as the case may be) from the payee
or payer of a registrable maintenance liability, the Registrar must,
  make such
variations (if any) to the particulars entered in the Child Support
Register in relation to the liability as the Registrar considers
necessary or desirable to:

Comment: (a) enable the relevant order or maintenance agreement to be
given effect to under this Act; or
(b) take account of the happening of the relevant affecting event;
as the case requires.

Answer (score 4):

*If any* is being used as an ellipsis of *If there are any.* It's saying the Registrar must make variations if there are any variations, but it's entirely possible that there are not any variations to make.

Answer (score 1):

**If** there are variations, the Registrar **must** make the variations to the particulars entered in the Child Support Register.